# set sessionStorage with postMessage (crossdomain) not firing on iOS Safari or Chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage, session-storage

I have a parent page with an iframe. When I load the parent I send the url to the iframe (postMessage) and set that url to sessionStorage.

Now, this works exactly how I want it when testing on desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE).

**Problem**

However, on mobile/ios11 chrome and safari the message is not being sent and sessionStorage is not being set on the iframe's domain. **Note** I am not blocking cookies on phone settings.

**Parent**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var message = window.location.href;
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
};
```

**Child (iframe)**

```
//global vars
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var url = sessionStorage.getItem("customer_url");


//listen
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    // clear
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem("customer_url");

    // set
    var customer_url = `${event.data}`;
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("customer_url", customer_url);
});

//show top bar if storage is set
window.onload = function() {

    if (sessionStorage.getItem("customer_url") === null) {
        header.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
        header.classList.add("active");
    }

    var close = document.getElementById("close-hosted");
    close.href = customer_url;

};
```

**Fixed**

Use iframe.onload rather than window.onload.

Comment: Window load event fired when all syncronous content loaded, so in case of mobile device, which is slower than desktop,  event may fires before your iframe complete loading and set message listener. This easy to check, just add a 1 sec timeout before sending message in your main window.

Comment: Thanks that did not help but it gave me an idea. Rather than window.onload I do iframe.onload and it works.